# Increases Time of Splash Screen in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, splash-screen, launch-screen

I am working in a Swift 4 project and I had set the LaunchScreen.storyboard. I want to increase the display time of it.

I have seen solutions over here but they are in Objective-C, but I want a solution in Swift. Does anybody know how can I achieve this.

Comment: If you have a solution that works in obj-c, you can convert it to swift.

Comment: You need to be more specific. If you have an Obj-C answer, either convert it to Swift - same APIs, just different syntax - or show *your* best conversion to it and ask for help.

Comment: @rmaddy but bro its client requirement...we need to do as client want.. :) :(

Comment: Fine, that's their silly choice. But do NOT use any solution that sleeps. That is a very, very bad solution. Do not accept such an answer.

Comment: okay bro Thank You :) @rmaddy

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Best approach is make a fake splash screen.

And The hack solution is that, create a thread with time interval,
Add the following code in appDelegate method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

Do not do this type of approach, because this approach also may lead to rejection from App Store.

```
Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 3)
```

Comment: No, do not do this. NEVER sleep on the main queue. iOS will kill your app for taking too long to startup.

Comment: Total agree with @rmaddy and Sam. Best approach is make a fake splash screen.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible if you make a fake splash screen that you will have full ability to make any animation and sound effect. A fake splash screen is just a UIView or UIViewController that shown after app launch.

For example, add a real splash screen with the same background color with your fake splash screen. On the fake splash screen, you can make it show as long as you want.

Comment: If you really must punish your users, this is the proper solution.

Comment: This is what apple says about launch screens `The launch screen isn’t an opportunity for artistic expression. It’s solely intended to enhance the perception of your app as quick to launch and immediately ready for use. Every app must supply a launch screen.`

Answer (score 1):

According to me, the one of the solutions is to create new view controller which is having your splash design & redirect it after the time whatever u want...

Redirecting code id here...

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [self TabBarPush];

});
```

Benefits of using new view controller as splash is that you can customise it, code it & can also add any type of animations in your splash screen as e.g.. loader etc..

If you want some data to be fetched before redirecting then you can code like this also...

```
[[syncEngine sharedEngine] syncAllData:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self TabBarPush];
}];
```

Thank you..